# Multi color Range Bar based on values in ssrs 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

I designed a range bar using SSRS 2008.  Scenario i am currently having issue as follows:

My range bar is based on "Activity Name", Start Date & Time, End Date & Time.

Eg: Activity A starts on 1st April @ 5AM and ends @6PM.  My requirement is range bar should show 5AM to 10AM in one color, 10 AM to 2 PM in one color and 2PM till 6 PM in another color.

Basically i am trying to show shifts involved in completing that activity.  Hope my requirement is clear. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to visualize your chart but if your displaying a total number of Activities (Activity Name) in one bar and the data has a date/time field, you can use the Charts's Series Properties' Fill property.

On your chart values, click the drop-down by your Value Series and go the FILL tab. For the **Color** expression, you'll want something like:

```
=IIF(FORMAT(Fields!YourDateTimeField.Value, "HH") >= 5 AND FORMAT(Fields!YourDateTimeField.Value, "HH") < 10, "BLUE",  
 IIF(FORMAT(Fields!YourDateTimeField.Value, "HH") >= 10 AND FORMAT(Fields!YourDateTimeField.Value, "HH") < 13, "PURPLE", 
 IIF(FORMAT(Fields!YourDateTimeField.Value, "HH") >= 14 AND FORMAT(Fields!YourDateTimeField.Value, "HH") < 18, "RED", "ORANGE")))
```

This would color the Activities between 5 am and 10 am as blue, 10 am and 2 om as purple and 2pm and 6 pm as red - any outside these ranges would be Orange.